# Не работает перенос строки (react)

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Сервер возвращает текст, где перенос строки отмечен как "\n", но на странице перенос не отображается. Пробовала заменять его на "\n\r" либо "\r" - то же самое.

```
let newBody = this.props.body.replace(/\n/g, '\r')
```

При замене "\n" на "<br>" или "<br/>" тег отображается вместе с текстом, переносов нет.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что делать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можете попробовать решить проблему с помощью css свойства white-space.
Сам только сегодня столкнулся с подобной проблемой :)

Comment: Подошло, спасибо!